# Need help to edit the attributes of XML using C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have the below XML.

```
 <Account xmlns:i="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Uanet>  
<Charges xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Urjat">
<a:Charge> 
<a:ChargeActualName>Recent Payment</a:ChargeActualName>                                                    
<a:ChargeAmount>-190.0200</a:ChargeAmount>      <a:ChargeId>recent_payment</a:ChargeId> 
<a:ChargeRatePerUnit i:nil="true"/>  
</a:Charge>
</a:Charges> 
</Account>
```

I am trying to remove the attribute i:nil="true" for all the XML elements. I have copied only a part of XML. Please suggest me a way to do this!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an xslt transform to prevent copying some nodes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Uanet>"
                >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <!-- copy all nodes except the i:nil attributes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='i:nil'] | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The language may seem weird, but it is pretty good for applying generic rules.

input.xml is transformed into output.xml using filter.xslt rules.

Here is the C# launching the transformation :

```
XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument("input.xml");
XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
myXslTrans.Load("filter.xslt");
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("output.xml", null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
```

Link to working solution :
http://1drv.ms/1QlOdEO

Regards

Comment: @Juluru, did you give a try at my answer ? In my solution I remove all i:nil attributes. Is it what you expected ?